# How can I randomize the position of my instances here?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using geometry nodes to animate soda cans getting pressed into a cube.
The main issue is the animation path. The instances clearly follow a cube like shape and I was hoping to randomize it a somehow.

Currently it looks like this: https://youtu.be/Ki55nzpjFpA

And this is my node setup: [image: node setup]

I'm also open to completely different methods, I'm still very new to blender and don't really know how best to approach a subject.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a *Set Position* node after the *Instance on Points* and plugged a *Random Value* node into the offset of *Set Position*. Then I just animate the max value of the *Random Value* node.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the distribute point on faces to randomize the positions of your cans in your grid

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to animate these into a cube shape? I experimented a bit but can't find a way to unrandomize them.